# vim function only works properly the first time

Tags: vim, autocmd

I wrote a function in vim to insert text in "paste"-mode. If I leave the insert mode, the script also leaves the paste mode (set nopaste). Therefore I used the autocommand InsertLeave.
The Problem is, that the "set paste" command works only the first time I call the function. If I want to call it once more I have to restart vim.

This is the vim function:

```
function Paste_from_clipboard()
    execute "normal! :set paste\<CR>\<Esc>o"
    execute "startinsert"
    autocmd InsertLeave * execute "normal! :set nopaste\<CR>"
endfunction

map <Leader>p :call Paste_from_clipboard()<CR>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how  VimScript works. Every line (be it
on .vimrc,  a plugin, a  syntax file) is just  an ex command,  where the
starting `:` is not needed. So when you write this:

```
execute "normal! :set paste\<CR>\<Esc>o"
```

You're basically calling  a ex command (`:exec`) which  calls another ex
command (`:normal`)  which then simulates  normal mode to what?  To call
yet another ex command (`:set`) and  using key codes to execute it. Why?
You can just use the final ex command directly:

```
set paste
```

This is  also happening in your  auto command. Also, it  is important to
notice that you're  recreating an auto command every time  you call your
function. A  simple fix is then  to remove your extra  commands and move
the auto command  outside the function, so it is  created only once. The
execution will  then happen every  time the event is  triggered (without
another event listener being created over and over.

```
function Paste_from_clipboard()
    set paste
    startinsert
endfunction

autocmd InsertLeave * set nopaste

map <Leader>p :call Paste_from_clipboard()<CR>
```

Check  the  `:h pt`  for   the `pastetoggle`  option.  It  might  be  an
alternative to what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I truly misunderstood how VimScript works.